# How do I reinstall php on a mac?

Tags: php, macos, terminal

I have been wanting to upgrade php5 to php7 on my macbook but i just don't know how. I tried using homebrew and a couple other methods I found online but I just don't know how to complete it.

As a result php5 has been deleted from /usr/local.

How can i get php5 back and then how do i upgrade it to php7?

I want the newest version because I have a minecraft server that I run on my computer that used to use php5 but now requires php7. I have the latest macbook with the latest os.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.php

Comment: read this . https://denbeke.be/blog/servers/migratingupdating-from-php-5-to-php-7-on-os-x-macports/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using homebrew, you can go with [homebrew-php](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php). You can install multiple version of PHP with this, and easily switch the version if you want

Or, you can use homebrew with php as usual

```
brew tap josegonzalez/php
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install php55
```

If you want to upgrade to PHP 7 but still keep current PHP 5, you should unlink PHP 5 first

```
brew unlink php55
brew install php70
```

Then you can use PHP 7.
And if you want to switch back to PHP 5, just unlink PHP 7 and link PHP 5

```
brew unlink php70
brew link php55
```

Comment: i tried doing what you suggested but it does not work. i keep getting an error that there is no such keg